TidyHtml5Managed does not work when doc.Markup is set to false
I'm trying to use TidyHtml5Managed (https://github.com/gabrieleteotino/TidyHtml5Managed) to tidy-up html strings. I do not want pretty printed output so I set doc.Markup = false;, but then the produced output is always a null char (\0). Is this a bug or do I need to set some other doc properties to make it work?
